# Can't type VietNamese in Visual Studio Code

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, input-language

I have a problem with my editor Visual Studio Code.
I can't type any VietNamese word on it although i have fcitx-unikey or ibus-unikey installed and activated.
I can solve this problem in Sublime Text 3 but not to VS Code.
Please help me !
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you install VSCode from Ubuntu software? If yes, can you try to remove ít and download `.deb` directly from https://code.visualstudio.com/ and re-install.

I think VS Code from Snap is not a latest version so some bugs didn't fix. Please look at image below.

[image: Typing Vietnamese on VS Code]